# How to test performance of 100 parallel 15GB file download using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

my test scenario's are to identify the performance metrics of 10 and then 100 concurrent downloads of a 15GB file.

Unfortunately my RAM is only 8GB and cannot increase any more than that.

ive tried using 'save response to file' listener but that is using memory instead of disk space.

Do we have any script to store response i.e. file being downloaded to disk space instead of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, the only way I can think of is writing your file retrieval logic using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and send the content of the file to /dev/null using i.e. [NullOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html) or [EntityUtils.consumeQuietly()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consumeQuietly(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) function to discard the output.

Comment: I've used "Save response as MD5 Hash?" and comparing the hash value of all requests.